# Reverse a modal segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue

In my app, there's a login screen. On that login screen, there's also a register button. If a user clicks the register button, a modal segue is executed to present a register view.

However, when the user clicks 'cancel', I want to do the same animation but then in reverse. So basically the register view should slide down. I created a custom segue for this, but I don't know how to properly animate this. How can I do this?

**ReverseModalSegue.m**

```
#import "ReverseModalSegue.h"

@implementation ReverseModalSegue

- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                    animations:^{
                        [src.navigationController popToViewController:    [src.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];;
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

**ReverseModalSegue.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ReverseModalSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

Comment: You don't need a custom segue, use an unwind segue (or just dismiss in code).

Comment: @rdelmar, how do I do that then?

Comment: See this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them/15839298#15839298

Answer (score 0):

More than creating a segue, you should create a custom `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, I highly recommend you [THIS TUTORIAL](http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/) where is everything very good explained.

Greetings.